# Android video recording & Thumbnail

Tags: android

In my application, I record some video. After recording the video I need to show the video thumbnail; I get the thumbnail but it is only an image -- it does not contain the play image on the thumbnail.

How can I add the play icon to the image?

```
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 1;
Bitmap curThumb =
    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr, id,
    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);
image.setImageBitmap(curThumb);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a play icon to your android project, merge this icon image with the thumbnail bitmap you are getting from the video and show it.

Hope this help!